# PHP asXML Write (Append) To File

Tags: php, xml, append

I have a PHP which is fetching XML data from a long list of URLs.  It appears that this is over-writing the xml.log file, how can I get it to append to the file instead?

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM urls_list";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("MySQL Error..." . mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $url = $row['url'];   
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
   echo $xml->asXML('xml.log');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) which maintains a `FILE_APPEND` flag:

```
file_put_contents('xml.log', $xml->asXML(), FILE_APPEND);
```

Alternatively, use [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with append mode:

```
$fh = fopen('xml.log', 'a');
fwrite($fh, $xml->asXML());
fclose($fh);
```